# C#: deserialize xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I can't deserialize the xml-File below: how to do?

some infos:

- object Machine has one or several "BOX" and "Component"
- object Box has several "Component"
- object Component can contain several "Subcomponent"
- each object contains GeoVar with a plenty of inner elements beginning with D such as D1,
  D3 and so on. It varies form an object to another.
- each IfcProp has descriptive inner element.

XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Configurator>
    <Machine OrderNumber="123456" name="ProjectABC" posindex="null" position="G" revision="01">
        <GeoVar/>
        <IfcProp/>
        <Box assemblyCode="GGA" assemblyIndex="01" los="BoxLos" losindex="01" name="BoxName" classnumber="175892" type="BOXType">
            <GeoVar>
                <D1>2000.0</D1>
                <D2>2400.0</D2>
                <D5>2000.0</D5>
                <D7>1</D7>
                <Start_x_Coordinate>0</Start_x_Coordinate>
                <Start_y_Coordinate>0</Start_y_Coordinate>
                <Start_z_Coordinate>500</Start_z_Coordinate>
                <inSide>6</inSide>
            </GeoVar>
            <IfcProp/>
            <Component assemblyCode="FTE" assemblyIndex="01" name="Filter" classnumber="171115" type="FILTER">
                <GeoVar>
                    <D5>1894.0</D5>
                    <D4>1894.0</D4>
                    <D16>600.0</D16>
                    <B>1894.0</B>
                    <H>1894.0</H>
                    <T>600.0</T>
                    <BA>1894.0</BA>
                    <HA>1894.0</HA>
                    <TA>600.0</TA>
                    <Start_x_Coordinate>53</Start_x_Coordinate>
                    <Start_y_Coordinate>53</Start_y_Coordinate>
                    <Start_z_Coordinate>1153</Start_z_Coordinate>
                    <Layout>1</Layout>
                    <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                    <inSide>6</inSide>
                    <D6>70.0</D6>
                    <D7>64.0</D7>
                    <D8>32.0</D8>
                    <D9>610.0</D9>
                    <D10>610.0</D10>
                    <D12>3</D12>
                    <D13>3</D13>
                    <D19>2</D19>
                    <D20>2</D20>
                </GeoVar>
                <IfcProp>
                    <Typ>592x592x600x8 </Typ>
                    <Volume>1.777,8 m³/h</Volume>
                </IfcProp>
            </Component>
            <Component assemblyCode="" assemblyIndex="01" name="RevChambre" classnumber="000000" type="AUDITCHAMBER">
                <GeoVar>
                    <B>1894.0</B>
                    <H>1900.0</H>
                    <T>600.0</T>
                    <B>1894.0</B>
                    <H>1900.0</H>
                    <T>600.0</T>
                    <BA>1894.0</BA>
                    <HA>1900.0</HA>
                    <TA>600.0</TA>
                    <Start_x_Coordinate>53</Start_x_Coordinate>
                    <Start_y_Coordinate>53</Start_y_Coordinate>
                    <Start_z_Coordinate>553</Start_z_Coordinate>
                    <Layout>1</Layout>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="GGT" name="Door" classnumber="196387">
                        <D1>1900.0</D1>
                        <D2>600.0</D2>
                        <D5>1200</D5>
                        <D10>2</D10>
                        <D16>1</D16>
                        <D20>3</D20>
                        <D21>2</D21>
                        <D23>2</D23>
                        <D24>2</D24>
                        <D25>2</D25>
                        <D50>2</D50>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="GGT" name="Door" classnumber="196387">
                        <D1>1500.0</D1>
                        <D2>600.0</D2>
                        <D5>1200</D5>
                        <D10>1</D10>
                        <D16>1</D16>
                        <D20>2</D20>
                        <D21>2</D21>
                        <D23>1</D23>
                        <D24>2</D24>
                        <D25>2</D25>
                        <D50>0</D50>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="WAS" name="WESS" classnumber="169683">
                        <D4>600.0</D4>
                        <D5>1894.0</D5>
                        <D6>46.0</D6>
                        <D7>6</D7>
                        <D9>1</D9>
                        <D10>1</D10>
                        <D13>1</D13>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                </GeoVar>
                <IfcProp/>
            </Component>
            <Component assemblyCode="" assemblyIndex="02" name="RevChambre 2" classnumber="000000" type="AUDITCHAMBER">
                <GeoVar>
                    <B>1894.0</B>
                    <H>1900.0</H>
                    <T>1474.0</T>
                    <B>1894.0</B>
                    <H>1900.0</H>
                    <T>1474.0</T>
                    <BA>1894.0</BA>
                    <HA>1900.0</HA>
                    <TA>1474.0</TA>
                    <Start_x_Coordinate>53</Start_x_Coordinate>
                    <Start_y_Coordinate>53</Start_y_Coordinate>
                    <Start_z_Coordinate>1373</Start_z_Coordinate>
                    <Layout>1</Layout>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="GGT" name="Door" classnumber="196387">
                        <D1>1900.0</D1>
                        <D2>600.0</D2>
                        <D5>1200</D5>
                        <D10>1</D10>
                        <D16>1</D16>
                        <D20>3</D20>
                        <D21>2</D21>
                        <D23>2</D23>
                        <D24>2</D24>
                        <D25>2</D25>
                        <D50>2</D50>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="GGT" name="Door" classnumber="196387">
                        <D1>1500.0</D1>
                        <D2>600.0</D2>
                        <D5>1200</D5>
                        <D10>2</D10>
                        <D16>1</D16>
                        <D20>2</D20>
                        <D21>2</D21>
                        <D23>1</D23>
                        <D24>1</D24>
                        <D25>2</D25>
                        <D50>2</D50>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <SubComponent assemblyCode="WAS" name="Wa" classnumber="169683">
                        <D4>1474.0</D4>
                        <D5>1894.0</D5>
                        <D6>46.0</D6>
                        <D7>6</D7>
                        <D9>1</D9>
                        <D10>1</D10>
                        <D13>2</D13>
                    </SubComponent>
                    <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                </GeoVar>
                <IfcProp/>
            </Component>
        </Box>
        <Component assemblyCode="AKA" assemblyIndex="01" name="Pipe" classnumber="185087" type="DUCTJOIN">
            <GeoVar>
                <D2>1000.0</D2>
                <D1>1000.0</D1>
                <D3>500.0</D3>
                <B>1000.0</B>
                <H>1000.0</H>
                <T>500.0</T>
                <BA>1000.0</BA>
                <HA>1000.0</HA>
                <TA>500.0</TA>
                <Start_x_Coordinate>947</Start_x_Coordinate>
                <Start_y_Coordinate>490</Start_y_Coordinate>
                <Start_z_Coordinate>0</Start_z_Coordinate>
                <Layout>1</Layout>
                <inOut>1</inOut>
                <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                <inSide>6</inSide>
            </GeoVar>
            <IfcProp>
                <Drag>0 Pa</Drag>
                <certificat>No </certificat>
                <velocity>0,3 m/s</velocity>
                <Volume>1.000 m³/h</Volume>
            </IfcProp>
        </Component>
        <Component assemblyCode="AKA" assemblyIndex="02" name="Pipe 2" classnumber="185087" type="DUCTJOIN">
            <GeoVar>
                <D2>1000.0</D2>
                <D1>1894.0</D1>
                <D3>500.0</D3>
                <B>1000.0</B>
                <H>1894.0</H>
                <T>500.0</T>
                <BA>1000.0</BA>
                <HA>1894.0</HA>
                <TA>500.0</TA>
                <Start_x_Coordinate>947</Start_x_Coordinate>
                <Start_y_Coordinate>53</Start_y_Coordinate>
                <Start_z_Coordinate>2900</Start_z_Coordinate>
                <Layout>1</Layout>
                <inOut>2</inOut>
                <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                <inSide>6</inSide>
            </GeoVar>
            <IfcProp>
                <Drag>0 Pa</Drag>
                <certificat>No </certificat>
                <velocity>2,3 m/s</velocity>
                <Volume>16.000 m³/h</Volume>
            </IfcProp>
        </Component>
        <Component assemblyCode="JAK" assemblyIndex="01" name="Jalousie" classnumber="185931" type="MULTILEAFDAMPER">
            <GeoVar>
                <D1>476.0</D1>
                <D2>1000.0</D2>
                <D4>100.0</D4>
                <B>476.0</B>
                <H>1000.0</H>
                <T>100.0</T>
                <BA>476.0</BA>
                <HA>1000.0</HA>
                <TA>100.0</TA>
                <Start_x_Coordinate>196</Start_x_Coordinate>
                <Start_y_Coordinate>53</Start_y_Coordinate>
                <Start_z_Coordinate>400</Start_z_Coordinate>
                <Layout>1</Layout>
                <inOut>1</inOut>
                <AirDirection>1</AirDirection>
                <inSide>6</inSide>
            </GeoVar>
            <IfcProp>
                <Count>0 </Count>
                <Wall>wa</Wall>
                <Lame>la</Lame>
                <Cadre>Or</Cadre>
                <Volume>15.000 m³/h</Volume>
            </IfcProp>
        </Component>
    </Machine>
</Configurator>
```

What i have tried:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace HelperTest
{
    public class Tests
    {

        [Test]
        public void Machine()
        {
            string file = @"Directory\file.xml";
            Deserialize(file);
        }

        public void Deserialize(string file)
        {
            List<Machine> MachineList = new List<Machine>();

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Machine));
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file)))
                {
                    Machine result = (Machine)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    MachineList.Add(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create object from xml string", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Machine")]
    public class Machine : AttributesSet
    {
        // elements
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoVar")]
        public GeoVar geoVar { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IfcProp")]
        public IFCProp ifcProp { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BOX")]
        public List<BOX> box { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Component")]
        public List<Component> component { get; set; }
    }

    public class AttributesSet
    {
        //all attributes are optional

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        string name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "classnumber")]
        string classnumber { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OrderNumber")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "position")]
        public string position { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "posindex")]
        public string posIndex { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "revision")]
        public string revision { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "assemblyIndex")]
        ushort assemblyIndex { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "assemblyCode")]
        ushort assemblyCode { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        string type { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "BOX")]
    public class BOX : AttributesSet
    {
        // elements
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoVar")]
        public GeoVar geoVar { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IfcProp")]
        public IFCProp ifcProp { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Component")]
        public List<Component> component { get; set; }

    }
    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "GeoVar")]
    public class GeoVar
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Start_x_Coordinate")]
        public string start_x_Koordinate
        {
            get; set;
        }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Start_y_Coordinate")]
        public string start_y_Coordinate
        {
            get; set;
        }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Start_z_Coordinate")]
        public string start_z_Coordinate
        {
            get; set;
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "B")]
        double B { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "H")]
        double H { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "T")]
        double T { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BA")]
        double BA { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "HA")]
        double HA { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TA")]
        double TA { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AirDirection")]
        ushort airDirection { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Layout")]
        ushort layout { get; set; }
        //
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "inSide")]
        ushort inSide { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "inOut")]
        ushort inOut { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SubComponent")]
        public List<SubComponent> subComponent { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "IfcProp")]
    public class IFCProp
    {
        // TODO: How to manage a varietie of Elements?
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "SubComponent")]
    public class SubComponent : AttributesSet
    {
        // elements
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoVar")]
        public GeoVar geoVar { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IfcProp")]
        public IFCProp ifcProp { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Component")]
    public class Component : AttributesSet
    {
        // elements
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GeoVar")]
        public GeoVar geoVar { get; set; }
        //
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IfcProp")]
        public IFCProp ifcProp { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SubComponent")]
        public List<SubComponent> subComponent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing root element class i.e. `Configurator`

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "Configurator")]
public class Configurator
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Machine")]
    public Machine Machine { get; set; }
}
```

And while de-serializing use `Configurator` instead of `Machine`.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configurator));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file)))
{
    Configurator result = (Configurator)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    MachineList.Add(result.Machine);
}
```

Comment: thx Danial, works well! now my question is how create an GeoVar Class or object witch varies from one object to another. Some Boxes have D1/D2/D3 ..D55 as sub-xml-elements and other boxes or components have D29/D13...and so on. the same for the IfcProp with completly different xml-element from depends on the object...hope you can follow! thx

Comment: You can define all the possible `DX` individually in `GeoVar` and `ifcProp` and only the elements inside XML will be populated others will remain 0.
Or you can define a parent class which will have all the DX properties and then use it as parent for GeoVar, ifcProp.